# Xpath for getting name and URL pattern

Tags: xpath

I am trying to do the Xpath to get value of following for L7:Name and L7:UrlPattern

```
<l7:Name>SERVICE List</l7:Name>
<l7:UrlPattern>/*</l7:UrlPattern>
```

**request**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l7:List xmlns:l7="http://ns.l7tech.com/2010/04/gateway-management">
    <l7:Name>SERVICE List</l7:Name>
    <l7:Type>List</l7:Type>
    <l7:TimeStamp>2018-10-03T10:14:59.409-05:00</l7:TimeStamp>
    <l7:Link rel="self" uri="https://company/restman/1.0/services?sort=name&amp;order=desc"/>
    <l7:Link rel="template" uri="https://company/restman/1.0/services/template"/>
    <l7:Item>
        <l7:Name>Service not found Catch-all</l7:Name>
        <l7:Id>cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1</l7:Id>
        <l7:Type>SERVICE</l7:Type>
        <l7:TimeStamp>2018-10-03T10:14:59.406-05:00</l7:TimeStamp>
        <l7:Link rel="self" uri="https://company/restman/1.0/services/cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1"/>
        <l7:Resource>
            <l7:Service id="cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1" version="2">
                <l7:ServiceDetail folderId="cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e6ae" id="cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1" version="2">
                    <l7:Name>Service not found Catch-all</l7:Name>
                    <l7:Enabled>true</l7:Enabled>
                    <l7:ServiceMappings>
                        <l7:HttpMapping>
                            <l7:UrlPattern>/*</l7:UrlPattern>
                            <l7:Verbs>
                                <l7:Verb>GET</l7:Verb>
                                <l7:Verb>POST</l7:Verb>
                                <l7:Verb>PUT</l7:Verb>
                                <l7:Verb>HEAD</l7:Verb>
                            </l7:Verbs>
                        </l7:HttpMapping>
                    </l7:ServiceMappings>
                </l7:ServiceDetail>
            </l7:Service>
        </l7:Resource> 
    </l7:Item>  
</l7:List>
```

**The Xpath I tried**

```
/l7:List/l7:Item//*[self::l7:Name or self::l7:UrlPattern]/text()
```

**This gives me the output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
Service not found Catch-all
Service not found Catch-all
/*
</result>
```

I was wondering how to get only one name and the associated URLPattern for that.

Something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
Service not found Catch-all
/*
</result>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to be more specific, e.g.

```
/l7:List/l7:Name/text() | /l7:List/l7:Item//l7:UrlPattern/text()
```

[Online Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cl7%3AList%20xmlns%3Al7%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fns.l7tech.com%2F2010%2F04%2Fgateway-management%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AName%3ESERVICE%20List%3C%2Fl7%3AName%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AType%3EList%3C%2Fl7%3AType%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3ATimeStamp%3E2018-10-03T10%3A14%3A59.409-05%3A00%3C%2Fl7%3ATimeStamp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3ALink%20rel%3D%22self%22%20uri%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Frestman%2F1.0%2Fservices%3Fsort%3Dname%26amp%3Border%3Ddesc%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3ALink%20rel%3D%22template%22%20uri%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Frestman%2F1.0%2Fservices%2Ftemplate%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AItem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AName%3EService%20not%20found%20Catch-all%3C%2Fl7%3AName%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AId%3Ecd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1%3C%2Fl7%3AId%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AType%3ESERVICE%3C%2Fl7%3AType%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3ATimeStamp%3E2018-10-03T10%3A14%3A59.406-05%3A00%3C%2Fl7%3ATimeStamp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3ALink%20rel%3D%22self%22%20uri%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Frestman%2F1.0%2Fservices%2Fcd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AResource%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AService%20id%3D%22cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1%22%20version%3D%222%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AServiceDetail%20folderId%3D%22cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e6ae%22%20id%3D%22cd5853a68445a82e1384676c9fc8e7c1%22%20version%3D%222%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AName%3EService%20not%20found%20Catch-all%3C%2Fl7%3AName%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AEnabled%3Etrue%3C%2Fl7%3AEnabled%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AServiceMappings%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AHttpMapping%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AUrlPattern%3E%2F*%3C%2Fl7%3AUrlPattern%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AVerbs%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AVerb%3EGET%3C%2Fl7%3AVerb%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AVerb%3EPOST%3C%2Fl7%3AVerb%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AVerb%3EPUT%3C%2Fl7%3AVerb%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cl7%3AVerb%3EHEAD%3C%2Fl7%3AVerb%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AVerbs%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AHttpMapping%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AServiceMappings%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AServiceDetail%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AService%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AResource%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fl7%3AItem%3E%20%20%0A%3C%2Fl7%3AList%3E&=l7%3AResource&extract=%2Fl7%3AList%2Fl7%3AName%2Ftext()%20%7C%20%2Fl7%3AList%2Fl7%3AItem%2F%2Fl7%3AUrlPattern%2Ftext()&=%2F&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)